# I mistakely Deposit my BTC to my Yobit.net BCC Address, How can i Get it Back

Tags: bitcoin-core, cross-chain-recovery

Help me,
I am not able to Contact Yobit for help, Can anyone give me there email
I By Mistake sent my BTC to my BCC Address of Yobit, Can I get it recovered
I heard That BTC and BCC have same Structure Thus BTC and BCC have same address and Private key, Thus I Think Yobit has BCC address and Private Key thus They also Can Get my BTC Using That, I need help

I am new to It, I need to get my BTC, Hope Someone Hears me and Reply with Help and Help me resolving it with Yobit...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry man but you are not able to get your money back unless someone from Yobit sends it back. Try to get in touch with their support team.